# Is there a limit on the amount of pages I can track with Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I am looking to provide analytics for a website which has user generated pages (which would therefore require a unique tracking ID for each page).

Is there a limit to the amount of different pages I can track?

I have looked around documentation provided by Google on data limits but have found no information regarding this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your assumption that you need to have a different tracking ID for each user generated page is not necessarily correct. You can track the entire website using the same Google Analytics property. I assume you're worried about exposing analytics data about the page generated by user A to user B accidentally. To prevent this from happening, what you can do is configure a custom dimension in Google Analytics that records which user a page belongs to. Then, when exposing analytics data to a specific user, you can make sure to **only** expose data about pages that belong to that specific user.

Comment: This solved my problem. By adding a custom dimension I am then able to filter the analytics using the dimension. Thanks.

Comment: Glad it worked. Make sure that your custom dimension has a scope of "Hit".

Answer (score 1):

You can create up to 50 propertys per account. 
The trackable documents should be unlimited. Only limited by pageviews per month (10 million /month).

[limits and quotas](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/limits-quotas)

Comment: Looking at the admin panel on GA, I can see that you can have a maximum of 50 properties, each with a maximum of 25 views. If a user creates pages dynamically within the same domain, would I not be limited to these 25 views?

Comment: Note that I am referring to your comment about having unlimited trackable documents